# Conditional Sequency Count, Paste Specific Columns

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-formatting

I have an R Data Frame that looks as follows:

```
id | seq_check | action | ct
123 | end | action_a | 1  
123 | start | action_b | 4  
123 | start | action_c | 1  
456 | end | action_d | 1  
456 | start | action_e | 16  
456 | start | action_f | 4  
456 | start | action_g | 5  
456 | start | action_h | 2  
456 | start | action_i | 1
```

The 'end' tag only occurs once per id and is the endpoint of a specific sequence by an id. What I would like to have a is a data frame that looks as follows:

```
id | seq_action | ct  
123 | action_a <- action_b | 4  
123 | action_a <- action_c | 1  
456 | action_d <- action_e | 16  
456 | action_d <- action_f | 4  
456 | action_d <- action_g | 5  
456 | action_d <- action_h | 2  
456 | action_d <- action_i | 1
```

Does someone know how I can do that in R? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id', we `paste` the 'action' that corresponds to 'end' in 'seq_check' with the 'action' for 'start' in 'seq_check', along with subsetting 'ct' where 'seq_check' is 'start'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,.(seq_action=paste(action[seq_check=="end"],action[seq_check=="start"],
              sep=" <- "), ct = ct[seq_check=="start"]) , by =  id]
#    id           seq_action ct
#1: 123 action_a <- action_b  4
#2: 123 action_a <- action_c  1
#3: 456 action_d <- action_e 16
#4: 456 action_d <- action_f  4
#5: 456 action_d <- action_g  5
#6: 456 action_d <- action_h  2
#7: 456 action_d <- action_i  1
```

NOTE: Only one package used.

---

Or using `na.locf` with `dcast`

```
library(zoo)
dcast(setDT(df1), id+ct~seq_check, value.var = "action")[, .(id, 
              seq_action=paste(na.locf(end), start, sep=" <- "), ct)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr);

spread(df, seq_check, action) %>% fill(end) %>% 
      mutate(seq_action = paste(end, start, sep = " <- ")) %>% 
      select(id, seq_action, ct)

   id           seq_action ct
1 123 action_a <- action_c  1
2 123 action_a <- action_b  4
3 456 action_d <- action_i  1
4 456 action_d <- action_h  2
5 456 action_d <- action_f  4
6 456 action_d <- action_g  5
7 456 action_d <- action_e 16
```